# How can extra context be passed to django-crispy-forms field templates?

Tags: django-crispy-forms

Inspecting the field.html template in the bootstrap3 template pack of django-crispyforms, I noticed an additional context variable, "tag", referenced. You can see this on [line 12](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/field.html#L12) and [line 41](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/field.html#L41) of the template. How can I specify a value for "tag" in the context used to render the field.html template for a particular form field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tag` context variable is set in the template, not the view. If you're using the built-in bootstrap3 template pack it's defined in the template that is including `field.html`. If the including template does not define `tag` then it defaults to `div`.

Ex: `table_inline_formset.html` [line 41](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/table_inline_formset.html#L41).

Answer (score 8):

I used palestamp's response as a guide to build a more generic `CustomCrispyField`.  You can pass `extra_context` as a `kwarg` to `CustomCrispyField`.  `extra_context` is just a dictionary that I access in my custom template that I copied from `crispy_forms`.

```
from crispy_forms.layout import Field
from crispy_forms.utils import TEMPLATE_PACK


class CustomCrispyField(Field):
    extra_context = {}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra_context = kwargs.pop('extra_context', self.extra_context)
        super(CustomCrispyField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, form, form_style, context, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK, extra_context=None, **kwargs):
        if self.extra_context:
            extra_context = extra_context.update(self.extra_context) if extra_context else self.extra_context
        return super(CustomCrispyField, self).render(form, form_style, context, template_pack, extra_context, **kwargs)
```

And I would use it like so in my form:

```
self.helper.layout=Div(CustomCrispyField('my_model_field', css_class="col-xs-3", template='general/custom.html', extra_context={'css_class_extra': 'value1', 'caption': 'value2'})
```

And my template would have code similar to the following:

```
{% crispy_field field %}
<button class="btn {{ css_class_extra }}">{{ caption }}</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just override standard crispy Field like this:

```
class LinkField(Field):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.view_name = kwargs.pop('view_name')
        super(LinkField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, form, form_style, context, template_pack=CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK):
        if hasattr(self, 'wrapper_class'):
            context['wrapper_class'] = self.wrapper_class

        if hasattr(self, 'view_name'):
            context['view_name'] = self.view_name
        html = ''

        for field in self.fields:
            html += render_field(field, form, form_style, context, template=self.template, attrs=self.attrs, template_pack=template_pack)
        return html
```

Then just pass additional variable ('view_name') in overridden template.

In Layout it will look like this:

```
Layout(
    LinkField('field_name', template='path_to_overridden_template',
                      view_name='variable_to_pass')
)
```